# What rounded corner approach should I take?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rounded-corners

So there's no shortage of information out there on rounded corners and I've been through much of it and I'm posting to get the opinions of the communities on this point.

My scenario is that we're developing a rounded corner dependent design, mainly used for interactions (`<button>` and `<a>`). We are going to use border radius for the good browsers on the block that play nice with it and then use the server to send down JavaScript to browsers that don't.

What I'm wondering is what to use to up scale the browsers that ignore border radius CSS? I need something that works on button as well as a, div etc. I've been looking at the following and have found that some don't play nice with `<button>`. Also the site already uses jQuery.

http://www.curvycorners.net/ - http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/

http://www.html.it/articoli/niftycube/index.html

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Edit: I've also looked at http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/ and at this point it seems the strongest candidate to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the one that works and gets the project done on time. Beyond that you're not likely to get much useful feedback on this as they all suck from one standpoint or another depending on how you view images, javascript, semantics, adding extra tags to "make it work", etc.

Comment: Agreed. I answered this question for someone else the day before yesterday. The comment after was that it wasn't advisable because it was a semantic markup nightmare. But the method works and it doesn't break at all. Best of all, no pictures to use and no scripting, strictly CSS and HTML. Even more important is my boss liked it.

Comment: Here's the technique, let the comments fly:

http://blog.benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners/

Comment: For what it is worth, I use the css styles in the JQuery UI stylesheets since I already have it loaded. I'm not trying to do anything fancy and it adds a nice touch.

Answer (score 3):

They're all much the same. I've used the last one (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/) and it works great. Almost certainly has more corner styles than you care about, but at 8KB, it's not *too* heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you should just go with the -webkit-border-radius as well as the -moz-border-radius to support all Webkit and Mozilla browsers. To have a fix with IE, there is a javascript function to do that. Hope that helps!

Comment: When I can, I just let IE be its ugly self. It's not always an option, of course.

Answer (score 1):

spiffycorners.com has a 100% css approach that even works in IE6!  This is what I use...

Answer (score 0):

I've had some experience with the Javascript methods described above and they all work great. Personally I would go for something that integrates well with existing Javascript frameworks, like JQuery (which would be my personal choice).

Applying the effect to a lot of elements can be very cumbersome for the browser in terms of memory usage however. I've had quite a lot of browser crashes due to me being too generous with applying corner effects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Stu Nicholis' CSS play? His [Snazzy Borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/snazzy2.html) and [Krazy Korners](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/krazy.html) are a nice cross-browser solution.