# Portable round corners on html button

Tags: html, css, layout, button

I have a simple html button that I wrap into a `div`. I know that such buttons may render differently on different browsers.

```
<div id="but_begin"><button type="button" id="but2_begin">Go</button></div>
```

I have set the following CSS on the button (using JQuery):

```
$("#but2_begin").css({
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    width:50
});
```

and it renders as follows:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the shadows around it and make the corners round. Now, I am getting a little scared when I read all the info available on the net about button layout and round corners. It does not seem to converge at all.

**My question:** how can I set round corners on a HTML button in a portable way? Is this possible with CSS only? Or should I use a library? Or should I use a different HTML tag or method?

Comment: Specifically, what browsers do you need to support? And have a business reason. Supporting IE6 and even 7 can make little sense these days. If you want it to be truly portable use images.

Comment: I like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648870/what-rounded-corner-approach-should-i-take

Comment: To remove the "shadows" set "border: none;" in your buttons css. Rounded corners require CCS3 so will not work in < IE9 unless you use something like http://css3pie.com or an image background.

Comment: @mrtsherman I don't really care about IE6 and IE7. I am interested in recent browsers, say versions released in the past 2 years and who can handle HTML 5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS3 to generate rounded corners and text-shadows in a portable way. http://css3generator.com/ is a neat tool that can help you do so.

More and more browsers are supporting CSS3 and major browsers such as the latest versions of Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera, and Firefox (covering over 90% of users) certainly support it.

For instance, this code from http://css3generator.com/ reliably creates rounded borders in a multitude of browsers.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

The "shadow" you are talking about ids the border of the button. Set `border:none;` and it is gone.
Rounded Corners you can do with pure CSS, but only when it is ok, that older browser will not render it round. Only the newer ones that support CSS3 wil round the corners.

```
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```